# Protractor Angular 4 E2E Unexpected Token Import

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

After several days and countless threads here and elsewhere, I cannot seem to get my e2e tests running. It seems like either there are compiling issues from TS to JS or the protractor library isn't loading. When I run the code below, I get the following message:

> [13:18:39] E/launcher - Error:
>   /Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/e2e/e2e.spec.ts:23 import {
>   E2eTest } from './e2e.page'; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>       at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at /Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:93:5
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Jasmine.loadSpecs (/Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:92:18)
>       at Jasmine.execute (/Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:197:8)
>       at /Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:132:15
>       at Function.promise (/Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:682:9)
>       at /Users/shawncasey/doctor_web_portal/node_modules/protractor/built/frameworks/jasmine.js:104:14 [13:18:39] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100

If I change my `import {element, by, browser} from 'protractor';` to `const by = require('protractor');` I get the message `by.css is not a function`.

There is a post already here: [SyntaxError: Unexpected token import when trying to import protractor in e2e test for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553101/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import-when-trying-to-import-protractor-in-e2e-tes), but I'm not sure about transpiling my ts. I thought that was handled. If it isn't, how do I do it?

Here's the relevant code:
Page object:

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class E2eTest {

    getUsernameBox() {
        return element(by.id('exampleInputEmail1'));
    }
    getPasswordBox () { 
        return element(by.id('exampleInputPassword1'));
    }
    getLoginButton() {
        return element(by.class('.btn-success'));
    }

    navigateTo() {
        return browser.get('/');
    };

}
```

Test suite:

```
import { E2eTest } from './e2e.page';

describe ('Doc Portal App', () => {
    let page: E2eTest;

    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new E2eTest();
    });

    it ('Should log in to portal', () => {
        page.getUsernameBox().sendKeys('#####');
        page.getPasswordBox().sendKeys('#####');
        page.getLoginButton().click();
    });
});
```

Running Jasmine 3.1.0, Protractor 5.4.0, Typescript 2.9.2. My protractor.conf.js seems fine, but here's my tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2016",
    "baseUrl": ""
  },
  "exclude": [ ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have this in your onPrepare? `require('ts-node').register({ project: 'path/to/tsconfig.json' });` If not that could be your issue. Try running `npm i --save-dev ts-node` and adding that code snippet in your onPrepare. Also, for your `by` example, I think it should be `require('protractor').by` and it will work;