# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" with protractor.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, protractor

Facing below error while executing the test though syntax are fine. Could anyone guide me how to resolve this ?

Is there any specific changes need to be done if we are using protractor.ts (typescript) instead of protractor.js (javascript) ?

I have changed to protractor.ts as I have to import some class from typescript test file which I cannot do using protractor.js

***Error:***

```
[18:34:13] E/configParser - C:\Users\agent-ux\e2e\src\q-e2e\protractor.conf.ts:2
import { SpecReporter } from 'jasmine-spec-reporter';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
An unexpected error occurred: undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! agent-ux@0.15.0 e2e: `ng e2e --webdriver-update=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the agent-ux@0.15.0 e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

***Protractor.ts:***

```
import { SpecReporter } from 'jasmine-spec-reporter';
import { HtmlScreenshotReporter } from 'protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter';

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
  specs: [
    './**/*.e2e-spec-q.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        'start-maximized',
        // '--headless'
      ]
    },
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  // directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 300000, // 5 minutes
    print: function () { }
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
        dest: 'e2e/src/q-e2e/screenshots',
        filename: 'failed-screenshots.html',
        captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true
      })
    );
  },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token import when trying to import protractor in e2e test for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553101/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import-when-trying-to-import-protractor-in-e2e-tes)